# Oracle SQL Update using cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, cursor

I have a question about how to using a CURSOR to update an email domain name by using an new email domain name.  ex(gmail.com->hotmail.com)

execute `procedure('gmail.com','hotmail.com' )`

Here is what I write. please help me out, thank you!

```
create procedure PR_Q3
is P_NewEamil varchar2(50); P_Email_Address varchar2(50); exceptionforemail exception;
cursor E_info is select Email_Address from Broker where P_Email_Address = Email_Address
for update of Email_Address;
begin 
open E_info;
fetch E_info into P_NewEamil;
while E_info%found loop 
if(P_NewEamil like '%.com') then 
update Broker set Email_Address = P_NewEamil where P_Email_Address = Email_Address;
```

Answer (score 2):

Why you want to use the cursor when it can be done using a simple `update` statement as following:

```
UPDATE BROKER
SET
    EMAIL_ADDRESS = REPLACE(P_NEWEAMIL, :OLD_DOMAIN, :NEW_DOMAIN)
WHERE
    REGEXP_LIKE ( P_NEWEAMIL,'.*@'|| :OLD_DOMAIN|| '$' );
```

Please add more `WHERE` conditions according to your requirements.

Cheers!!

Comment: it has bad bind variable error with old_domain and new_domain

Comment: Just replace old and new domain with your actual names. And remove : also